# How to solve without using trig?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, angle

> In the diagram, five identical squares have been placed together.
>
> [image]
>
> What is $\angle ABC$?

It's easy with trig but can't find an answer without using it. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Reflect point $C$ about point $B$.

Comment: I've done that, but not quite sure how to proceed

Comment: If $D$ is the reflection of $C$ about $B$, compare $|AD|$ and $|BD$|.

Comment: Ah so is ADB 90 degrees, and since it is isosceles the other angles are 45 respectively?

Comment: Bingo! :) ......

Comment: Thanks! How would I prove that it is 90 degrees though?

Comment: Compare "slopes".

Comment: Ah ok I understand now thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help. Write your own solution as an answer so that the question doesn't linger in the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I hinted-at in the comments:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $BD$ be an altitude of $\Delta ABC$, $E$ be a mid-point of $DC$, $\Delta AEF\sim\Delta CDB$,

such that $B$ and $F$ are placed at the different sides respect to $AC$, and $BG$ be an altitude of $\Delta BFE$.

Thus, since $EF=2BD$ and $DBGE$ is a square, we obtain: $$\Delta ABD\cong\Delta FBG,$$ which gives $$AB=BF,$$ $$\measuredangle ABF=90^{\circ}$$ and $$\measuredangle BAF=45^{\circ}.$$
Id est, $$\measuredangle ABC=180^{\circ}-\measuredangle BAC-\measuredangle BCA=180^{\circ}-\measuredangle BAC-\measuredangle FAC=180^{\circ}-\measuredangle BAF=135^{\circ}.$$